# Required scope for events API on private repos

Tags: github, github-api

I'd like to use the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/) to read comments, issues and so on for a given user with the [GitHub Events API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/).

I've already accomplished that with OAuth authentication using the `repo` scope. That's a big overkill since I just want to read events and this scope grants almost everything. The [API doc](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/) doesn't specify anything, and I can't find a more limited [scope](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes).

I've been testing with different personal access token scopes but only `repo` makes requests return private events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the [scope](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes) `repo` if you want to retrieve events originating from private repositories.

At this point this is the only scope for the job.